# Excel 2010 - "Sticking" Info in Column B to Info in Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Column A = Column Z (a name).  Column B (a number) is information specific to each name in Column A.   The information in Columns Z thru ZZ is deleted every night and repopulated the next day, but the names are shuffled.

If Joe is in Cell Z4 today, his name also appears in Cell A4 and a number (5.55) is next to his name in Cell B4.  "Tomorrow," Joe's name appears in Cell Z10 when Columns Z thru ZZ are populated via copy & paste.

I need the number 5.55 (in Column B) to follow Joe no matter where his name appears in Column A (and Z).

The numbers in Column B are manually entered and not a part of what is pasted in Columns Z thru ZZ.

(Columns C thru J contain Joe-specific information.  All information in Columns K thru Y are formulas that are calculated based on what is pasted in Columns Z thru ZZ).

I have tried to use VLOOKUP by “tying” the info in Column B to the names in Column A, but I have had no luck assigning the number (5.55) to Joe.  I don’t know if this is because Column A = Column Z.  Maybe VLOOKUP will work if I “tie” Column B to Column Z.  I would not think that would matter, but it may.

Thanks. -Jon

Comment: Let's see your vlookup formula, an explanation of what you expect to be happening with your formula, and a description of what is happening (or not happening) as the case may be.

Comment: Where does the number 5.55 come from? I mean, if you put a formula in column B, where should the formula find that number, in what column? Is it column ZA? (the one to the right of column Z)

Comment: As you describe the problem, formulas alone will not solve it. Basically, you need a list of *values* that preserve the association of names and numbers from the end of one day to the beginning of the next. Then, you can do a lookup on that list so that, given a reshuffled set of names in column A, you can create a list of the numbers associated with the resorted names and then copy and paste the numbers from the lookup into column B. This can be done by hand or by VBA code.